# centos8 ssh Timeout client not responding

Tags: centos, ssh

We just installed centos8 on one of our servers. The same (barebone) machine ran centos7 just fine before. Now we have many interrupted connections; many ssh connections get interrupted but not all... For example:

```
> ssh centos8
> ssh some-other-machine
The authenticity of host 'some-other-machine (1.2.3.4)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is SHA256:POwKbdOx0s5IOxVL9gObdtLEbf7oqDDmdHXF9jaA8uQ.
RSA key fingerprint is MD5:0d:85:b1:fb:e0:cd:00:fb:ba:41:8c:57:ee:0c:7e:2f.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? Connection to centos8 closed by remote host.
Connection to centos8 closed.
```

So I am on this centos8 machine, and try to connect to another machine. `ssh` asks me to confirm the authenticity, but without waiting for an answer just interrupts the whole ssh session, and I am kicked out of centos8...

I found this in the `systemd` logs:

```
Oct 08 15:04:36 Kubernetes01 sshd[9039]: Timeout, client not responding from user root 10.1.86.100 port 57514
Oct 08 15:04:36 Kubernetes01 sshd[9022]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user root
```

It is happening only from time to time and I haven't succeeded in finding a pattern. The machine is very powerful and is certainly not highly loaded on cpu, RAM, disk space...

Comment: Can't this be an other system using the same IP? arping with option -D  (for duplicate address detection) can be used to detect such conflict.

Comment: @A.B thanks for the hint, but this is not the case (just checked to be sure). We just updated this server reusing the same IP...